# How to make and condition with or in laravel query

Tags: laravel-5

My query is as below

```
SELECT * FROM `user_register` 
INNER JOIN `locationdetail` on `locationdetail`.`userid` = `user_register`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `lifestyle` on `lifestyle`.`userid` = `user_register`.`id` 
WHERE `lifestyle`.`drink` in (2) and 
( `locationdetail`.`state_id` in (4121) or `locationdetail`.`country_id` in (38))
```

In this query how to make bracket inner query in laravel model

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried sub query, but It' s not working

Comment: Cool, could you add you attempt.. might be just a small thing

Comment: ->Where(function ($query) {
                $query->orwhereIn("locationdetail.state_id", (4121));
               $query->orwhereIn("locationdetail.country_id", (38));  
            })

Comment: the above query is work, but when  I am passing state array or country array in function then it will give undifined varaible

Comment: $preference->where(function($query){
$query->orwhereIn("locationdetail.state_id", $state);$query->orwhereIn("locationdetail.country_id", $country);  })->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry there got distracted

```
    $drinks = [1];
    $state_ids = [1,2]
    $country_ids = [1,2,3]

    $someModel
    ->join() // enter your joins here
    ->whereIn('lifestyle.drink', $drinks)
    ->where(function( $q1 ) use ($state_ids, $country_ids) {
       // insert the whereOr queries here against the $q1 using the data in `use` params 
    })
    ->get();
```

To check your query there is a `toSql()` function you can use in laravel too.